# Python: Appending to an instance attribute from inside a function

Tags: python, class, instance

I am trying to write a basic card game for fun, but trying to make as much of it as possible applicable to future card games.Here is my code.

```
decks = [  ]
players = [  ]

class Player:
global players
def __init__( self, name ):
    self.hand = [  ]
    self.name = ''
    self.score = 0
    self.name = 'playerX'
    self.score = 0
    players.append( name )


class Deck:
    global decks
    global players

def __init__( self, name ):
    self.SUITS = [ 'C', 'D', 'H', 'S' ]
    self.RANKS = [ '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ]
    self.deck = [  ]
    for r in self.RANKS:
        for s in self.SUITS:
            self.deck.append( ( r, s ) )
    decks.append( name )

def shuffle( self ):
    shuffle( self.deck )

def display( self ):
    for e in range(0, len( self.deck ), 4):
        for i in self.deck[e:e+4]:
            print i,
        print

def dealXtoOne( number, deck, player ):
    ''' number of cards from a deck to named player'''
    if len( deck.deck ) >= number:
        for n in range( 0, number ):
            player.hand.append( deck.deck.pop(  ) )
            print 'Player1 hand: ', p1.hand
    else:
        return 'Insufficient cards in the deck.'

def dealXtoEach( number, deck ):
    ''' number of cards from a deck to each player'''
    global players
    print 'debug 0'
    if len( deck.deck ) >= number*len( players ):
        print 'debug 1'
        for cards in range( 0, number*len( players ) ):
            print 'debug 2'
            for player in players:
                print 'debug 3'
                print player
                print player.hand
                player.hand.append( deck.deck.pop(  ) )
                print player.hand
    else:
        return 'Insufficient cards in the deck.'



def value( card ):
    if card[ 0 ] == 'J': return 11
        elif card[ 0 ] == 'Q': return 12
        elif card[ 0 ] == 'K': return 13
        elif card[ 0 ] == 'A': return 14
        else: return card[ 0 ]

def topCard( deck ):
    return deck.deck[ -1 ]

def color( card ):
    if card[ 1 ] in [ 'Diamonds', 'Hearts' ]:
        return 'Red'
    else:
        return 'Black'


p1 = Player( 'p1' )
p2 = Player( 'p2' )
d = Deck( 'd' )

d.display(  )
print p1.hand
dealXtoOne( 3, d, p1 )
d.display(  )
print p1.hand
dealXtoEach( 3, d )
d.display(  )
```

I'm sure it's garbage, and it's clearly a work in progress, but I am teaching myself to program. Sorry if your eyes bleed!

So dealing X cards to one player works fine, but dealing X cards to N players each is not working. Here is my output:

```
('2', 'C') ('2', 'D') ('2', 'H') ('2', 'S')
('3', 'C') ('3', 'D') ('3', 'H') ('3', 'S')
...
('K', 'C') ('K', 'D') ('K', 'H') ('K', 'S')
('A', 'C') ('A', 'D') ('A', 'H') ('A', 'S')
[]
Player1 hand:  [('A', 'S')]
Player1 hand:  [('A', 'S'), ('A', 'H')]
Player1 hand:  [('A', 'S'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'D')]
('2', 'C') ('2', 'D') ('2', 'H') ('2', 'S')
...
('K', 'C') ('K', 'D') ('K', 'H') ('K', 'S')
('A', 'C')
[('A', 'S'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'D')]
debug 0
debug 1
debug 2
debug 3
p1

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\11583\Desktop\Personal\cardgame.py", line 94, in <module>
        dealXtoEach( 3, d )
    File "C:\Users\11583\Desktop\Personal\cardgame.py", line 60, in dealXtoEach
        print player.hand
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hand'
```

I can tell that it doesn't like that I am trying to append a tuple to the reference inside the dealXtoEach function of the instance of Player represented by the string in the players global variable. Sheesh, I am confused just explaining it.

So how can I get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error has nothing to do with appending to a tuple (and by the way, `players` is a list not a tuple- it's impossible to append to a tuple).

Instead, try replacing the line:

```
players.append( name )
```

with

```
players.append( self )
```

This way, the global `players` list won't contain a list of strings (which you can't use for much), it will contain a list of `Player` objects (which have, among other things, a `hand` attribute).

---

An extra note: a global `players` list isn't really necessary (and global variables are usually recommended against)- you could just pass around the `players` list. Secondly, `dealXToOne` and `dealOneToEach` should really be methods of the `Deck` class. Together, that would make the last few lines look something like:

```
players = [p1, p2]
d.dealXToOne(3, p1)
d.dealXToEach(e, players)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass around the players list"? I know global vars are frowned upon.

Comment: @user1515663: see my code example of `dealXToEach(e, players)`- make `players` an argument to the function

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand what you were doing. It works pretty much as I wanted now.

Answer (score 1):

Each `player` in your `players` list is a string, not a `Player` object, because of this line:

```
players.append( name )
```

replace with:

```
players.append( self )
```

Comment: David beat me to it, and I'll re-iterate his sentiment that you should try to eliminate all the global `players` lists